# Is there any support in NEST to execute the same command on multiple elasticsearch clusters?

Tags: elasticsearch, replication, nest

We have two elasticsearch clusters (in two different data centers) that must be synced in "almost real time", so we would like to send commands (via NEST) to both clusters.

Note: we don't want to use snapshot/restore since it requires closing the indexes before doing a restore.

Is there any native support in NEST to execute the same command (mostly "write" commands) on multiple clusters?

If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

I looked around defining multiple ConnectionPool but I'm not sure how to pass the multiple connection pools to the ElasticClient

Note: ATM we still use NEST 2.5.5 but we plan to move to NEST 5.x soon

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any native support in NEST to execute the same command (mostly "write" commands) on multiple clusters?

There's no native support for executing request atomically against multiple clusters, but it's possible to execute the same request against multiple clusters by having two instances of `IElasticClient`, one that uses `ConnectionSettings` that point to one cluster and the other using `ConnectionSettings` that point to the other cluster. Then, execute pass the same request to both client instances.

You might want to encapsulate operations against both clients within a type such that the need to make the request against two clients is handled in one place.

Comment: Hello,thanks for your help I understand what we would need to do. I just have a question regarding "Then, execute pass the same request to both client instances.". Do you mean we can create a "nest request" (for instance a BulkDescriptor) one time and (re)use it when calling the BulkAsync() API on each ElasticClient instance? or do we have to create the BulkDescriptor for each call?

Comment: Yes, you can create one bulk request and reuse it for both client calls